# Expected command error trying to embed NetLogo

Tags: java, netlogo

I am trying to embed NetLogo in a little personal project but am stuck after the first example. I managed to build and test this example:

https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Controlling-API#example-embedding

But now I'd like to get rid of reading the example «fire» file. This is what I did:

```
import org.nlogo.lite.InterfaceComponent;
public class TestNetLogo {
  public static void main(String[] argv) {
    try {
      final javax.swing.JFrame frame = new javax.swing.JFrame();
      final InterfaceComponent comp = new InterfaceComponent(frame);
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(
    new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.add(comp);
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }});
        System.out.println("here");
        comp.command("breed [turtles turtle]");
        System.out.println("there");
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Replacing `"breed [turtles turtle]"` with an empty string works, but with a non trivial string, this is what I get:

```
Expected command. at position 33 in
    at org.nlogo.compiler.CompilerExceptionThrowers$.exception(CompilerExceptionThrowers.scala:26)
    at org.nlogo.compiler.ExpressionParser.parseStatement(ExpressionParser.scala:83)
    at org.nlogo.compiler.ExpressionParser.parse(ExpressionParser.scala:55)
    at org.nlogo.compiler.CompilerMain$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(CompilerMain.scala:34)
    at org.nlogo.compiler.CompilerMain$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(CompilerMain.scala:29)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:772)
    at scala.collection.JavaConversions$JIteratorWrapper.foreach(JavaConversions.scala:573)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:73)
    at scala.collection.JavaConversions$JCollectionWrapper.foreach(JavaConversions.scala:592)
    at org.nlogo.compiler.CompilerMain$.compile(CompilerMain.scala:29)
    at org.nlogo.compiler.Compiler$.compileMoreCode(Compiler.scala:34)
    at org.nlogo.workspace.Evaluator.org$nlogo$workspace$Evaluator$$invokeCompiler(Evaluator.scala:175)
    at org.nlogo.workspace.Evaluator.evaluateCommands(Evaluator.scala:18)
    at org.nlogo.workspace.AbstractWorkspaceTraits$Evaluating$class.evaluateCommands(AbstractWorkspaceScala.scala:163)
    at org.nlogo.workspace.AbstractWorkspaceScala.evaluateCommands(AbstractWorkspaceScala.scala:19)
    at org.nlogo.lite.AppletPanel.command(AppletPanel.scala:137)
    at TestNetLogo.main(TestNetLogo.java:15)
```

Somebody here with an idea?

Comment: Would you try doing a command such as `create-turtles 5` and let us know if that works? `breed` statements are declarations, not commands, and can't be run by `command`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some RTFSource and some experiments, this is my solution,
thanks to [Seth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/86485/seth-tisue)'s
hint number 2:

```
import org.nlogo.lite.InterfaceComponent;
import org.nlogo.util.Utils;
import org.nlogo.api.ModelReader;

public class TestNetLogo {
  public static void main(String[] argv) {
    try {
      final javax.swing.JFrame frame = new javax.swing.JFrame();
      final InterfaceComponent comp = new InterfaceComponent(frame);
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(
    new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        frame.add(comp);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        try {
          String src = Utils.url2String(ModelReader.emptyModelPath());
          // Those null's are model name and model path.
          comp.openFromSource(null, null, src);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }
      }});
        comp.command("create-turtles 1");
        comp.command("ask turtles [ set heading 0 \n set color [255 255 255] \n pen-down \n fd 4 ]");
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`InterfaceComponent.command()` only works with commands — anything you would type in the Command Center. `breed [...]` is a declaration, not a command. In the NetLogo application, `breed [...]` always goes in the Code tab, never in the Command Center.

Secondly, in order to use InterfaceComponent at all, some sort of model has to be open — even if it's an empty model, one containing model settings but no code or widgets.

So your two possible solution paths are:

1) Synthesize a string containing a model (complete contents of an `.nlogo` file) containing the Code tab code (and anything else) you want, then open it using InterfaceComponent's `openFromSource` method (which it inherits from AppletPanel).

2) Open an empty model, then call InterfaceComponent's `setProcedures` method (inherited from AppletPanel) to replace and compile the contents of the Code tab.

If you go with route #2, the code for opening the default empty model is:

```
comp.openFromSource(
  org.nlogo.util.Utils.url2String(
    org.nlogo.api.ModelReader.emptyModelPath()));
```

haven't tested it, but I think that's right.

Comment: Thanks for those hints, but: `openFromSource` needs three params: `name` (of the model, so this is easy), `path` and `source`. I don't understand why I need both path and source. For suggestion number 1), is there a minimal/trivial model I can use?

Comment: I don't recall offhand (without digging in the source) how `path` is used (if `InterfaceComponent` even uses it at all). As for the minimal model, you can look at `empty.nlogo` in the NetLogo jar; it's what `emptyModelPath` accesses.

Comment: Thanks. No clue for `path`, but I guess that `org.nlogo.api.ModelReader.emptyModelPath()` is for providing a trivial model. I `System.out.println`ed the result and saw what could be the content of a `.nlogo` file.

Comment: That's the contents of `empty.nlogo` which is one of the files inside `NetLogo.jar`.